# Spring Security addFilterAfter using XML confirguation

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently using Spring Security 4 on Spring MVC. I try to config anti-CSRF using REST service, not servlet. This [post](http://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/) is very useful but it uses Java configuration. How can I convert

`http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);`

into an XML configuration environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XML can be following for addfilterAfter()

```
<http>
   <custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="org.security.filter.CustomFilter"/>
```

Hope it will help....